# Storage organization for many medium size byte arrays

Tags: c++, database, storage

I have thousands of photos at filesystem, at different directories. And program that can create metainfo about each photo. Size of each metainfo is byte array with size around ~16Kb. Size of one metainfo is equal to size of others.

I have to store it somewhere and somehow. And can choose whatever I want, still, I want something simple.

First idea that comes to mind is:

- create mig file, where metainfo will be placed one after one (first, second, third and etc). Maybe allocate for that file enough space at creation.
- create small DataBase, maybe at sqlite3, that would store link to
  each photo at filesystem (as path to that photo) and connected link
  to that storage with metainfo position.

Another idea:

- I can create for each XXXX.YYY photo file another one with name XXXX.YYY.MET, store it in same directory and let it contain all metainfo. Will that be faster to load them all?

Is that better then store bytes array in DataBase, in table fields? Is there better architecture solutions for that?
I don't need good speed at creation of such storage, but need speed of access to it, and ability to load many metainfo as fast as possible.

Comment: It kind of depends on the usage scenario ... Is Metainfo required for all Images at once or is it required to be random accessible for single Images out of it all. The first case calls for a single File because that will reduce seek times; However the larger that file gets, the longer it needs to scan through indices if random access is required. 
Windows does this with one Info file per directory (the thumbs.db)

Comment: I need access to whole heap often then to any part of it. So, keeping files seems nice solution...